# createdb / pg_restore has error: must be owner of extension

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

I get this error:

> ```
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC: 
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4034; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION pg_trgm  
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: 
> must be owner of extension pg_trgm
> Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_trgm IS 'text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams';
> ```

when I run this command:

```
PGPASSWORD="$db_pwd" createdb -U "$db_user" -h "$db_host" -p 5432 --no-password -e "$db_name"
```

how can I fix? I assume the right thing to do is make myself owner of the `pg_trgm` extension, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *not* the `createdb` command that causes this error, but a `pg_restore`.

This means that you restored a dump from a database with the `pg_trgm` extension as a non-superuser.

The extension itself is restored as

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
```

so this will not result in an error if the extension already exists, but the following

```
COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_trgm IS '...';
```

will cause an error for non-superusers.

You can safely ignore this error.

Comment: Supposedly the `pg_restore --clean` option will help here, as far as my testing goes. The problem is pg_restore will exit with non-zero unless I tell it to ignore that error somehow. The --clean option seems to accomplish that?

Comment: Only if you are a superuser (who can create and drop this extension). But as a superuser, you won't get the error anyway.

Comment: I get the error as a superuser.

Comment: @oemb1905 Hard to believe. Superusers are not restricted by permissions. Perhaps you are dealing with a hosted database and a user that is *called* superuser but is not really a superuser.

Comment: Yeah, no, I self host everything so I'm quite clear on the names of users, etc., and permissions of them. I got the issue fixed, however, but it was late and no recollection of what I did.